# where to find the reference Bayesian networks of XMLBIF(.xml) format?

Tags: bayesian-network

The XMLBIF(.xml) format is XML Belief Network Interchange File Format, which is one of the standard formats for the storage and manipulation of the Bayesian networks. It is widely used by some Bayesian Network tools but I cannot find many XML formant Bayesian networks from the internet... There are many BIF(.bif) format Bayesian networks I can find, such as [here](https://www.bnlearn.com/bnrepository/) and [here](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/labs/compbio/Repository/networks.html).

Where can I download the XMLBIF format Bayesian networks or are there any tools to convert the BIF format to XMLBIF format？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't find an answer, I just implemented a converter using C++ to convert BIF format to XMLBIF format.

https://github.com/jjiantong/BIF2XMLBIF